# Dapper QuerySingleOrDefault doesn't return null

Tags: c#, dapper

Why Dapper QuerySingleOrDefault doesn't return null?
I use hard qwery.
In result I have object with default fields.
I ran this query in DB Browser for SQLite, It returned 0 rows.

```
public static Sensor GetSensor(string ip, string sensorName)
    {
        string sql = @"SELECT ip, name, invert, enable FROM DeviceAndOids AS A JOIN
                        DeviceForMonitoring AS B ON A.deviceForMonitoringKey=B.key JOIN
                        DeviceTypes AS C ON B.deviceTypeId=C.id WHERE 
                        oidForDeviceKey IN (SELECT key FROM OidsForDevice WHERE 
                        deviceTypeId IN (SELECT deviceTypeId FROM DeviceForMonitoring WHERE
                                ip = @ip) AND
                                name = @sensorName)";

        using (IDbConnection cnn = new SQLiteConnection(LoadConnectionString()))
        {
            var result = cnn.QuerySingleOrDefault<Sensor>(sql, new { ip, sensorName });
            return result;
        }
    }
```

Comment: As you can see in the [documentation](https://dapper-tutorial.net/querysingleordefault), if there's no item it will return the default (nothing), if there's one item it will return the item and if there's many items it will return a exception. So it's not returning `null` because it's not supposed to return `null`.

Comment: @ikerbera, thanks, I was reading. Вut what is default in my case? I thought default for object is null

Comment: What is the value in `result`? You probably have a `Sensor` class variable with all it's properties at default value. ints at 0, strings at null, bools as false and so on.

Comment: @ikerbera I would like use if (result != null) { // do something}

Comment: Can you show your `Sensor` class? I'm sure we can find some property that you can check to know if you got no data.

Comment: @ikerbera I'm sorry. `Sensor` was `struct`  I'm nattentive as usual. I chenged it to `class`

Comment: So is it working now? Don't worry about being innatentive, we all have had this problem at some point.

Comment: yes, it works now

Comment: Maybe there was a good reason for sensor to be a struct. Changing for this purpose only seems a little strange?

Comment: @Magnus Maybe yes, If use struct, I can use `bool fieldsNotNull = sensor.DeviceName != null && ...`

Comment: What was the reason to use struct in the first place?
How about `cnn.QuerySingleOrDefault<Sensor?>`

Comment: @Magnus beckause it's small type, without actions. For data from DB

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Sensor` was `struct` . I changed it to `class`
It works now

Comment: Note: it *might* have worked (re `null`) if you had used `<Sensor?>` instead of `<Sensor>` - however, I strongly suspect that using `struct` for something that represents a data row is *probably* a bad idea that could cause multiple subtle confusions

Comment: Maybe, I didn't understand you very well. But I changed it to `class`. I didn't use `<Sensor?>`

Comment: fair enough; changing it to `class` is by far the best solution here